# Optimal Edge Coloring With Vizing's Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, theory, graph-coloring

I am trying to create a program that runs an optimal edge coloring on a graph. This simple (Not a multi-edge) graph is of variable size with regards to nodes and edges. I am having some trouble understanding exactly how to implement the algorithm, and what it does. Most my understanding of Vizing's algorithm comes from [this](http://www.jhuapl.edu/techdigest/TD/td2302/Gilbert.pdf) source, which has been very helpful.

From what I understand, the algorithm is broken up into two main parts: The `ColorGraph` and `ColorEdge` Functions. In the above source, Jeffrey M. Gilbert presents the pseudo code for the Color Graph Function as the following:

```
ColorMultiGraph(G, k)
    Initialize G' to be
        V(G') = V(g)
        E(G') = {}
    Initialize Φ' to be an (empty) coloring E(G') with k>=0 Colors
    EdgesLeft = E(G)
    While EdgesLeft != {} Do
        Select e from EdgesLeft
        Φ' = ColorEdge(e,G', Φ')
        E(G') = E(G') U {e}
        EdgesLeft = EdgesLeft - {e}
    End While 
    Return Φ'
```

I more or less understand what is happening with this pseudo code, especially with the help of the relevant section in the linked text. What I don't understand, and hope I can find some help with, is the `ColorEdge` function.

Roughly speaking, It talks about holes representing the lack of a colored edge on a given node. You chose an edge, `e` from a given list of uncolored edges, and compare the holes on the endpoints to find out if an edge can be colored. That is simple enough to understand. What confuses me is the case when no hole can be matched between the two.

You are supposed to use the Vizing fan sequence to change the holes on the nodes you are coloring. I've read the section a few times and I don't really understand how it works, especially in conjunction to the `G'` and Φ' variables that are passed to the function.

Could someone please explain what exactly is happening in this section of the algorithm? I'm not sure how to proceed with it since I generally don't understand what is happening between the different parts.